# How to parse a parsing expression grammar?

Tags: parsing, peg, recursive-descent

I can't seem to find the parsing expression grammar (PEG) of PEG itself.

How to parse a parsing expression grammar?

**Note** that this question is not about how to construct a recursive decent parser from a PEG, but rather for parsing a PEG.

Comment: Is there anything special about a PEG grammar, other than the interpretation of "first choice that accepts is taken"?  Why can't you do PEG with *any* standard context free grammar?

Comment: @IraBaxter My preference would be that the grammar is a PEG, other grammars would be fine too.

Comment: @IraBaxter: PEG is LL(*), infinite lookahead, first choice, no left recursion. Most grammars are intended for LR parsers.

Comment: @david.pfx:  Aha.  No left recursion.   OK, so you get the same headaches as ANTLR (except they allow some left recursion now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PEG Paper](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/lang/peg.pdf) ("[Parsing Expression Grammars: A Recognition-Based Syntactic Foundation](https://dx.doi.org/10.1145%2F964001.964011)") includes the grammar for PEGs.

Comment: That's a PEG grammar for PEGs?

Comment: @IraBaxter Yup, "Figure 1. PEG formally describing its own ASCII syntax". I wrote a metacircular PEG parser generator using that grammar (extended with actions), so it really does match itself. https://github.com/jkominek/pegleg/blob/master/pegleg.peg

Comment: Every PEG product I've looked at has its own grammar, mostly PEG. Surprisingly variable in details.

Comment: @david.pfx:  *Every* parser generator I've looked at has its own grammar.  The basic EBNF isn't usually different, but there's always a bunch of other details that are "surprisingly variable in details".